# manipulating json from string to int and calculating on it

Tags: javascript, json, data-manipulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNVtX.png)I have a list of numbers like this:

```
"2552086989552589"
"6724843711060148"
"9758289300869651"
"5048166833276726"
"2864448008247645"
"6803999652011971"
"9758289300869650"
"9083938527182086"
"4563447869509114"
"2552086989552588"
"6724843711060149"
"6803999652011970"
"4563447869509115"
"3227366834142384"
"3227366834142385"
"5048166833276727"
"5153186889177226"
"2864448008247644"
"9083938527182087"
```

they are output from this function

```
function validate (ban,cards){
return cards;
}
```

How can I get the output of cards and do a calculation, such as a sum of the double of the numbers within the "123123123", also those are a string currently so need to convert into an int first!

The goal is

```
    {"card":"2552086989552589","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"6724843711060148","isValid":true,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"9758289300869651","isValid":false,"isAllowed":false}
{"card":"5048166833276726","isValid":true,"isAllowed":false}
{"card":"2864448008247645","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"6803999652011971","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"9758289300869650","isValid":true,"isAllowed":false}
{"card":"9083938527182086","isValid":true,"isAllowed":false}
{"card":"4563447869509114","isValid":true,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"2552086989552588","isValid":true,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"6724843711060149","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"6803999652011970","isValid":true,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"4563447869509115","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"3227366834142384","isValid":true,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"3227366834142385","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}
{"card":"5048166833276727","isValid":false,"isAllowed":false}
```

is valid is taking the first 15 numbers, double them, sum them, then divide by 10. If the remainder is the last number then isvalid is true and isallowed is true.

UPDATE

THIS IS very close to working:

```
 function validateCards(bannedPrefixes, cardsToValidate) {
return cardsToValidate.map(function(card) {
    const digits = card.split ('').map(Number);
    const valid = digits.reduce ((acc,d)=>acc+d*2, 0)%10== digits[digits.length-1]
    return {
        card: card,
        isValid: valid,
        isAllowed: valid,
    }
})
}
```

I just need to see if cardstovalidate contains bannedprefixes and if it does need to return false

Comment: that worked! Now how can I do a mathematics function on each of those!

Comment: if i want to print the the original number like "original":"123123"and the print to the right of it "sum": "4553" how can I do that

Comment: a+b is throwing some errors

Comment: Do you want to print 2*card number?

Comment: I want to print {"card":"2552086989552589","isValid":false,"isAllowed":true}

Comment: i edited question

Comment: lol no it just did nothing.

Comment: empty output a and b are not defined anywhere else

Comment: i added to question with desired result

Comment: Include your code.

Comment: I added image of code

Comment: @JamesShelton, check my answer to see if it works for you.

Comment: lol ... "image of code" is frowned upon, and you haven't shown `validateCards` function - I guess expecting some code monkey to do it for you?

Comment: i was trying to keep it a secret lol thats all i was converting it back

Comment: elya answer below was very close it showed false at the wrong time though

Comment: Be clear with your desired output

Comment: the desired output it is listed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the digits, transform then numbers, multiply them by two, then add them and check if the modulo is equal to the last digit. So do something like this:

```
function validate (ban,cards) {
  return cards.map(
    function(card) {
        const digits = card.split('').map(Number);
        const isValid = digits.slice(0,15).reduce((acc,d) => (acc+d*2), 0)%10 == digits[digits.length-1];
        const isAllowed = isValid && ban.reduce((acc,f) => (card.match(`^${f}`) == null && acc),true)
        return {
            card: card,
            isValid: isValid,
            isAllowed: isAllowed,
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't produce the expected output - lol, because expected output is complete garbage :p

Comment: i do appreciate it but was not able to get it to work

Comment: got ride of the error your format is correct, but the results are incorrect

Comment: this is very close

Comment: what does acc, and d means

Comment: The acc is short for accumulator. It collects a value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: great. i forgot to mention there are banned prefixes

Comment: this is helpful but if it card includes 1034,5,993934,33,9
20 it needs to return false on isallowed

Comment: Well, you got the idea, on how to do it. You just have to modify the function and add your additional validations

Comment: so do if cards contains ban false?

Comment: not sure how that would look in the context of your return valid loop

Comment: before the return, you can check if the card contains your forbidden digits:

Comment: @JamesShelton I Added the check, so that it calculates isAllowed. It's basically doing the same, for checking each series of forbidden series of numbers to make sure they are not in the card number, if any of them is in the digits it'll return false in isAllowed

Comment: the forbidden series is a parameter

Comment: Ok, got it. Its there now `ban` should be an array with the forbidden prefixes. I also updated the `match` regex to act only on the beginning of the card number

Comment: TypeError: digits.match is not a function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: did you make a change or just post the reference im just checking

Comment: I posted the reference. Where are you running your code?

Comment: The error was right, it should be `card.match`, not `digits.match` because the regex should be run on the original card number

Answer (score 0):

```
function toDigits(str) { return str.split('').map(Number); }

function sum(accumulator, value) { return accumulator + value; }

function isCardValid(str) {
  var digits = toDigits(str);
  var sumOfFirst15 = digits.slice(0,15).reduce(sum, 0);
  var remainder = (2 * sumOfFirst15) % 10;
  return remainder === digits[digits.length - 1];
}

function isCardAllowed(ban, card) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ban.length; i += 1) {
    if (card.indexOf(ban[i]) !== -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function toCardWithValidation(card) {
  var isValid = isCardValid(card);
  return {
    card: card,
    isValid: isValid,
    isAllowed: isCardAllowed(ban, card),
  };
}

cards.map(toCardWithValidation);
```

Comment: great, one more thing if it contains 1034,5,993934,33,9
20 it needs to not be allowed

Comment: How do you want to check if the string contains another string?

Comment: any way as long as isAllowed shows false if it contains anything from ban from the validate(ban,cards)

Comment: Ban is an array?

Comment: yes the example at the bottom of the question is working well just need to add the ban factor